# Is $3x+\frac{1}{\lvert x\rvert_2}$ consistently closer to $2^{\infty}$ than $x$ is?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

In the p-adic metric space is $f(x)=3x+\frac{1}{\lvert x\rvert_2}$ consistently closer to $2^{\infty}$ than $x$ is for $x\in\mathbb{N_{>4}}$?  Or does it vary?

Here is what I have:

$2^{\infty}=0\implies$ the question is equivalent to whether $\lvert x\rvert_2>\lvert f(x)\rvert_2\quad\forall x$

If we break $x$ down into its odd and even factors $$x=a\cdot2^n:n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq0}\land a\in \{2\mathbb{N_{>0}}-1\}$$ then we have:$$f(x)=3a\cdot2^n+2^n=3(a+1)\cdot 2^n$$

We know $a$ is odd so if we factor $a+1$ into its odd and even factors we have $a+1=a_1\cdot2^m :m>0$

$\therefore f(x)=a_1\cdot2^{n+m}$

$$\implies\lvert f(x)\rvert_2=\frac{\lvert x\rvert_2}{2^m}:m>0$$

Comment: What is $2^{\infty}$? Pretty sure that's just $0$ in $2$-adic numbers.

Comment: Which it says in the question

Comment: Sure, but why even use the invented notation $2^{\infty}$ and leave it to later to figure it out? It's terrible notation which illuminated precisely nothing.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews because I wanted a clear chain of logic proving that $3x+\frac{1}{\lvert x\rvert_2}$ is consistently closer to $2^{\infty}$, so part of the question includes verification of the fact that $2^{\infty}=0$. Because I wanted to be clear e.g. that the series $(1,3,7,15,31,63,127,...)$ is convergent on $-1$. I should perhaps have used a limit instead but nevertheless as you see, receiving an answer to the question stated in this form illuminated something for me.

Comment: Maybe the OP was just being polite, reusing the terrible notation $2^\infty$ because it appears in the question...

Comment: @Did I wasn't being polite or reusing any notation. I just wanted to be totally $100\%$ sure that e.g. the sequence $(1,3,7,15,31,63,127,...)$ which clearly converges to $2^{\infty}-1$, converges to $-1$

Comment: Please read better: maybe **Shanye2020** reused the terrible notation $2^\infty$ in their answer because it appears in **your** question, not because they would condone it as you seem to imply (to justify the bad idea of having used it in your question).

Comment: @Did I get you now.  I had $2^\infty$ clue what you meant before.

Comment: ?? Please stop your nonconstructive comments (three addressed at me already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. I like to work with p-adic valuations, where $v_p(a) = n$ where $a = p^n x/y$. The norm of $a$ is defined as $p^{-v_p(a)}$.

Let $x\in\mathbb{N}_{>4}$ such that $v_2(x)=n$.

Then $v_2(f(x)) = v_2(2^n\cdot3a+2^n) = v_2(2^n(3a+1)) = n + v_2(3a+1) > n$ $($because $2|3a+1)$.

Hence $\Vert f(x)-2^\infty \Vert_2 < \Vert x-2^\infty \Vert_2 $.

Comment: Just a quicky, is the double-bars simply the 2-adic metric? i.e. the same thing for which I have used the single bars?

Comment: Yes it is. I was essentially just confirming that your answer was correct.